# Right to left or right-to-left?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Which is right? right to left or right-to-left?

The same question goes for left to right and left-to-right

Can't find this in any dictionary I use.

Context: the way the text is written is usually left-to-right. But there are also right-to-left languages.

Comment: You need to provide context; either _could_ be correct - but it is very definitely context-dependent.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin added context

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Here, a [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ei=jop4Wsd3xICBBq6nq-gG&q=%22is+a+right-to-left+language%22&oq=%22is+a+right-to-left+language%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l4.132624.133685.0.134568.5.5.0.0.0.0.114.397.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.395...0i7i30k1j0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.UX6IJWyPxZ8) shows that both are used predicatively.

Comment: Ngram shows the non-hyphened style is far more common.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=left+to+right%2C+left-to-right&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleft%20to%20right%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20-%20to%20-%20right%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

For the context given, the provided example is correct by convention - “left-to-right” and “right-to-left” are being used as ‘unitary’ adjectives, describing how a language is written (e.g., the Latin alphabet is used for left-to-right languages; the Arabic and Hebrew abjads are used for right-to-left languages).

Comment: In which cases should it be used without hyphens, then?

Comment: When it is not being used as a descriptor, it should probably be used without the hyphens: "To cast your vote in a mechanical voting booth, move the large lever from right to left."